# Issue in Code Igniter JOIN

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

i have this query in CI Active record Form

```
$this->db->select('companies.*,comp_permissions.user_id');
$this->db->from('companies');
$this->db->join('comp_permissions', 'companies.id = comp_permissions.comp_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

it generates query like this

```
SELECT `hs_companies`.*, `hs_comp_permissions`.`user_id`
FROM (`hs_companies`)
INNER JOIN `hs_comp_permissions` ON `hs_companies`.`id` = `hs_comp_permissions`.`comp_id`
```

But My Original query is

```
Select cb.*,cbp.user_id
from hs_companies cb
INNER JOIN hs_comp_permissions cbp ON 
(cb.id = cbp.comp_id AND cbp.status=2 AND cbp.user_id = 72)
```

so now how do i put multiple columns in JOIN function?

**UPDATE**

when i tried like this

```
$this->db->select('companies.*,comp_permissions.user_id');
$this->db->from('companies');
$this->db->join('comp_permissions', '(companieas.id = comp_permissions.comp_id AND comp_permissions.status = 2 AND comp_permissions.user_id = 72)','inner');
$this->db->get()->result();
```

It generate following result

```
SELECT `hs_companies`.*, `hs_comp_permissions`.`user_id` 
FROM (`hs_companies`) 
INNER JOIN `hs_comp_permissions` ON 
(`hs_companies`.`id` = `hs_comp_permissions`.`comp_id` AND comp_permissions.status = 2 AND comp_permissions.user_id = 72)
```

it doesnot add `hs_` my db prefix

Answer (score 1):

Can you set it in `WHERE` caluses?

```
$this->db->select('companies.*,comp_permissions.user_id');
$this->db->from('companies');
$this->db->join('comp_permissions', 'companies.id = comp_permissions.comp_id');
$this->db->where('comp_permissions.status', '2');
$this->db->where('comp_permissions.user_id', '72');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

or perhaps you can set your db prefix manually:

```
$this->db->join('comp_permissions', '(companies.id = comp_permissions.comp_id 
                                     AND hs_comp_permissions.status=2 
                                     AND hs_comp_permissions.user_id = 72)');
```

Comment: can we put `(` around `where` clause?

Comment: try it, but what's the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$this->db->select('companies.*,comp_permissions.user_id');
$this->db->from('companies');
$this->db->join('comp_permissions', '(companies.id = comp_permissions.comp_id 
                                     AND cbp.status=2 
                                     AND cbp.user_id = 72)');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: i did like that but it misses my db prefix